# Proxy error: Could not proxy request /users from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, proxy

I am trying to create a simple react app with node/express for the backend. When I start my app I get this error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /users from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

My front-end package.json looks like this

[image]

The front-end is pretty simple. `fetchUserData()` under `useEffect()` is what calls the backend.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  let [userData, setUserData] = useState([{}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`/users`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setUserData(data);
    };

    fetchUserData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello React World!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The backend is pretty barebone as I just started this project. I have no problem getting the correct response if I just request http://localhost:5000/users directly from the browser or postman:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  res.json({ users: ["Bob", "Sally"] });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

The error message appears when I try to load the front end on http://localhost:3000 which should then fetch the backend resource. I look at the network tab of chrome and for some reason it is going to port 3000 instead of 5000:

[image]

I've tried the below but no luck:

1. Closing my app. Deleting package-lock.json and node_modules, reinstalling them.
2. Add '/' to the end of the string for the "proxy" setting in package.json
3. Replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 in package.json
4. Tried adding "--ignore client" to dev script in server package.json
5. Tried adding "secure": false in client package.json

**Edit 1:** This issue is driving me crazy. If I remove the proxy from package.json, add cors to the server side, and use the absolute path of the endpoint instead of the relative path in my client-side fetch request, it works. But I would much rather use the relative path.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  let [userData, setUserData] = useState([{}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/users`);
      const data = await response.json();
      setUserData(data);
    };

    fetchUserData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello React World!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work!

After a lot of experimenting, I realized that this was indeed an environment problem. That explains a lot since the many other suggestions I tried worked for other people but not for me.

What had happened was that my client-side was using wsl for the terminal yet my backend was using PowerShell. When I switched both to wsl it worked. Or when I switched both to Powershell it also worked.

Answer (score 6):

Just don't use 'localhost'. Set proxy in *package.json* as 127.0.0.1 or whatever IP address your backend is running.

Font: hours trying every solution possible.

Comment: this works. Any idea what is the difference between localhost and 127.0.01?

Comment: @Nithur, best answer I found was that, in some cases, "localhost" is not translated properly to IP address "127.0.0.1", causing unexpected behavior. This is linked to the servers you are using and even the OS.

Answer (score 0):

From trying to replicate your issue I think in your proxy you have  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/", but then you also pass a fetch request for "/users" which would lead to a "http://localhost:5000//users.

I would imagine that when you were trying to figure this out that the issue was that you didn't restart your React App after changing the package.json to include the Proxy, and then by the time you restarted the React App, you had already added the extra "/".

Also in your browser console.log when, no matter where your proxy is it will come up with http://localhost:3000 as the address rather than your actual endpoint - it can be a bit of a red herring

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried "proxy": "http://localhost:5000" (without the slash at the end), restarted react, and still the same error, unfortunately. Thanks for the tip on the browser console.log though.

Comment: "proxy": "localhost:5000"  or  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000" ?  Sorry you're code looks alright from everything I've copied and pasted and I'm getting a response with no errors.  Was going to suggest CORS following that but I see that you've looked into that already

Comment: I meant "proxy": "localhost:5000". No luck :/

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case, I had copied an old project and started stripping it bare to create a new site, so I knew the guts of it was solid.  The answer regarding the terminals helped me solve it.

My specific problem was created when I changed the port on the client side for proxy.  Restarting Visual Studio Code cleared it (debugging using concurrently, fyi).  I changed the ports again to recreate the error again, and lo and behold, bug returned.  Pretty confident one variation can be solved by just rebooting VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

If your backend's port is:
http://localhost:5000

you need this for frontend
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",